# My laptop shows Reboot and Insert media device from where to boot(while booting without the pendrive I burned to install ubuntu). What should I do?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-10

Again, if the pendrive is inserted, it shows try ubuntu or install ubuntu, not the os I installed. I did it twice and found later that it says 'install alongside ubuntu' whereby I can't even boot ubuntu. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do, and the specific nature of the problem that you are encountering.  If you boot from the external USB drive, the options to either try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu are the expected choices.  Have you  installed Ubuntu onto the computer's hard disk using the bootable USB drive?  When you boot the computer without the USB drive inserted, is the error message that is displayed actually "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"?